# Who should create objects

Tags: api, architecture

I have a class `Game` and now I need to add players (`IPlayer`) to the game. And I'm thinking about two scenarios:

1. First approach

```
IPlayer AddPlayer()
```

In this scenario the caller does not have to worry about implementation of `IPlayer`. He get just an interface and cannot tamper with the object. The `Game` knows implementation details and can manage player's state, for example add points:

```
interface IPlayer
{
    int Points { get; }
}

class Player : IPlayer
{
   ...
   void AddPoints(int points);
}
```

2. Second approach

```
void AddPlayer(IPlayer player)
```

In this approach it's the caller who is responsible for delivering an object that meets the interface. Thus know sthe details.

I'm wondering: Is any of those approaches apparently better/worse?

Just a comment about my point of view:

My goal is to have clear API. And I think that the first approach is better. When I give a user my library then I give him just interface. All the details are maintained inside. (Similarly I could give an access to `IGame` that under the hood is an instance of `Game`)

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using a "composition" approach as Unity does. Don't create classes/interfaces modeled around specific game entities. Have a `GameObject` class instead, exposing a collection of `Component`s.

Each Component would add some features and behavior to the owning GameObject, like position, physics, stats and so on.

One `GameObject` instance can act as some sort of "game controller", spawning entities and keeping track of the score (or whatever rules your game has).